# Issue with dismissing modal programmatically after confirmation alert

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I need to display a confirmation alert when the users clicks the close button to confirm if the user does indeed want the modal to be closed however there is an issue with hiding the modal / preventing the modal from being hidden in the 2 solutions that I have tried

*How modal is set up (Not full code)*

```
<div class="modal fade" id="viewTicketModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable vertical-align-center">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
```

*Showing Of Modal*

```
<a><i class="voyager-eye viewBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewTicketModal"/></i></a>
```

**Attempted Solution 1 (Closing of modal by calling hide)**

*Hiding Of Modal*

```
<button type="button" class="btn cancelModalBtnColor" onclick="closeTicketDetailsModal(event)">Close</button>
```

*Function To Close Modal*

```
   function closeTicketDetailsModal(e){
        if(enteredEditModeBefore){
            let text = "Proceeding will discard all changes that you may have made\nDo you wish to continue?";
            e.preventDefault();
            if (confirm(text) == true) {
                console.log("Forgoing Changes!");
                $('#viewTicketModal').modal('hide');
                return;
            } else {
                console.log("You still want your changes!");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            console.log("HIDING MODAL");
            $('#viewTicketModal').modal('hide');
            return;
        }
    }
```

*Issue with solution*

Whilst it is able to hide the modal, it no longer allows me me to show the modal again when the button that triggers the modal is clicked.

**Attempted Solution 2 (Closing of modal by data-dismiss)**

*Hiding Of Modal*

```
<button type="button" class="btn cancelModalBtnColor" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

*Function To Close Modal*

```
$('#viewTicketModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

*Issue with solution*

It doesn't hide the modal from being dismissed despite already preventingDefault and returning false

***What am I doing wrongly?***

Comment: Don't use confirm/alert popups, use overlay with a button instead. The overlay will "absorb" any clicks and the button will tell the user's response.

Comment: @vanowm but how does it explain what is the issue at hand?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite inconvenient to understand your code without a working example collected in one place. But I'll show you a working example using the "event delegation" technique, which allows you to use as many buttons as you like to perform the same actions. I will also demonstrate the work of the modal window and the modal overlay, as @vanowm wrote.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
            let popup = document.querySelector(".popup"),
                overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay")

            document.addEventListener("click",(ev)=>{
                if(ev.target.closest(".js-call-popup")){
                    popup.classList.add("active")
                    overlay.classList.add("active")
                }

                if(ev.target.closest(".js-hide-popup")){
                    popup.classList.remove("active")
                    overlay.classList.remove("active")
                }
            })
        })
```

```css
button{
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.site{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
.btn{
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background-color: #e4cff3;
    border: 1px solid purple;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.btn:hover{
    box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
}
/*  popup   */
.popup{
    position: fixed;
    width: 30vw;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: 50vh;
    left: 50vw;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -40%, 0) scale(.8);
    padding: 2vw 3vw;
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: rgba(17, 12, 46, 0.15) 0px 48px 100px 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: .3s opacity, .3s visibility, .3s transform;
}
.popup.active{
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.popup__close-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top:  1vw;
    right:  1.4vw;
}
.popup__confirm-btn-cont{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2vw;
}
.popup__confirm-btn{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: red;
}
/* overlay */
.overlay{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: .3s opacity, .3s visibility;
}
.overlay.active{
    opacity: .4;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Modal window demonstration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main class="site">
        <button class="btn js-call-popup">Call popup</button>
        <button class="btn">Show product</button>

    </main>

    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="popup">
        <button class="popup__close-btn js-hide-popup">
            &#x274C;
        </button>
        <p class="popup__message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dolores in sed consectetur error adipisci quisquam sapiente sint accusantium, atque commodi.</p>
        <div class="popup__confirm-btn-cont">
            <button class="popup__confirm-btn js-hide-popup">Accept</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

The advantage of this code is that it is modern, functional and does not use jQuery. In 2022, you should try to be modern and technological.